# check for alpha only colors using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check for alpha only charachters only on a webpage using javascript

```
    Javascript
     function AlphaOnly(x,fieldname) {
     var valueToCheck=x.value;
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

     if(valueToCheck.length == 0) {
        alert("Please Enter a " + fieldname);
        x.focus();
         return false;
     }
     else if(valuetoCheck.match(/[\W_]/)){
         alert("Alpha only");
         }
     else if(letters.test(valuetocheck)) {
     alert("its working");
     }
}
```

It works if the field is empty but cant get it to work if its not alpha charachters entered
Also want to change the color of an element

```
        function ChangeColor(x) {
        x.style.backgroundColor="red";
         }
```

I didnt put in the html as the functions are being called, they just wont do what they are suppose to. 
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks
Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `valueToCheck` variable is not keeping consistent case, and that appears to be causing the problem here, because javascript's variable names are case-sensitive.

This fiddle shows a working example with nothing changed but the variable name fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/jt3RC/

Comment: thanks , the function is display the first alert if the field is empty but I can still enter any charachter into the field - only want to be able to put in alpha